# Why won't 0 unbox to integer?

Tags: c#, exception, casting, integer

I'm getting an "invalid cast" exception in this code, which is in the mousedown of a grid:

```
// Get the index of the row and column the mouse is over.
    rowIndexFromMouseDown = grdSale.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
    colIndexFromMouseDown = grdSale.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).ColumnIndex;
// Drag only if we're not over header, are over count, and there are some tickets
    if ((rowIndexFromMouseDown != -1)
        && (colIndexFromMouseDown == 2)
        && ((int)grdSale.Rows[rowIndexFromMouseDown].Cells["TypeCount"].Value > 0))
```

From the immediate window:

```
?rowIndexFromMouseDown
2
?colIndexFromMouseDown
2
?grdSale.Rows[rowIndexFromMouseDown].Cells["TypeCount"].Value
0
?(int)grdSale.Rows[rowIndexFromMouseDown].Cells["TypeCount"].Value
Cannot unbox '(grdSale.Rows[rowIndexFromMouseDown].Cells["TypeCount"]).Value' as a 'int'
```

The grid cell displays nothing, but the grid is populated from an XML file who's schema defined the value as integer with a value of zero. And as one can see, that's the value of the cell. So why can't it be unboxed into an integer so I can evaluate it?

Comment: Not sure why, but try using Convert.ToInt32() rather than a cast.  If that works, the thing in there is probably some other type that displays as if it were an int.

Comment: Call `GetType` on it and print out the name.  Then you'll know what the type *really* is and can cast it to that.  Perhaps it's a boxed `double`, or a boxed `short`, or a boxed `long`, none of which can be unboxed to an `int`.

Comment: @lukegravitt There most certainly is.  `object` does not have an overloaded greater than operator, nor does `int` have an overload comparing itself to an object.  You could use `Equals` to compare them for equality, but as we know (from the error message) that the value is not a boxed in, it will necessarily be false no matter what.  A boxed double of value `0` is not equal to the integer `0`.

Comment: @Servy Ah, you are right. I guess I didn't think about the fact that `Value` was of type `object` and does need to be unboxed manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is some type besides `int`, e.g. `double` or `string`. Even if it were an implicitly convertible type, e.g. `short`, it cannot be directly unboxed to `int` unless its type is `int`. You can use [`Convert.ToInt32(value)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23511zys.aspx) to convert the value.

Comment: Indeed, at @Servy's suggestion, I discovered the value to be Int64. I changed from a datatable to XML as a source for the grid defaults, so the former value came from a datatable typeof(int), and the XML xs:integer is Int32. Since all the values are little ones, I'll have to make everyone explicitly int16.